# Connecting to a Teradata DB thru SqlAlchemy using a Teradata Wallet in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata, wallet

I'm able to connect to a Teradata Database using sqlAlchemy using this connection string format:
`f'teradatasql://{TERADATA_USER}:{TERADATA_PASSWORD}@{TERADATA_HOST}/{TERADATA_DATABASE}?logmech={TERADATA_LOGMECH}?driver={TERADATA_DRIVER}'`

However, this requires me to use my US + PW which is fine for testing but in production, I need to use credentials currently stored in a Teradata Wallet.  I understand this means I have to use an ODBC connection (which I have).
The Teradata page (https://docs.teradata.com/r/63GsjfOEVAlNpiYs21jT1Q/NLWJ9CQvkKYVUyjvvLWfBA) tells me the connection string is

> For a connect function call containing the Teradata Wallet reference string:
>
> SQLConnect(hdbc, "mydsn", SQL_NTS, "myuid", SQL_NTS,"$tdwallet(RefString)", SQL_NTS);
>
> SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DSN=mydsn;UID=myid;PWD=$tdwallet(RefString);", SQL_NTS, szConnStrout, cbConnStrOutMax, &cbConnectStrOutLen, NULL);
>
> SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DRIVER={Teradata}; DBCNAME=platinum; AUTHENTICATION=LDAP;AUTHENTICATIONPARAMETER=authcid=$tdwallet(RefString1) password=$tdwallet(RefString2); ", SQL_NTS, szConnStrout, cbConnStrOutMax, &cbConnectStrOutLen, NULL);

This requires me to use SQLDriverConnect (like, where is that?!) or SQLConnect (again, what is that?!).  I'm bound to use sqlalchemy because of decisions made above my paygrade so I need absolute proof that it's just impossible to use or an example of HOW to do it...Has anybody been able to connect this way?

Python + sqlalchemy + teradata + td wallet

Comment: SQLDriverConnect / SQLConnect are part of the (C/C++) ODBC API. But the `teradatasqlalchemy` dialect / `teradatasql` driver doesn't use ODBC. It also doesn't support Teradata Wallet, but does support a [Stored Password Protection](https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver#StoredPasswordProtection) option. BTW:  the `?driver={TERADATA_DRIVER}` suffix shown in your connection string is being ignored.

Comment: Fred.  I discovered the ?driver option being ignored when I did my testing a while back with 'bad' drivers to see what errors it would pop out and none did.  Blank, Bad, or Good drivers are all ignored...I built my own encryption process to store passwords but corporate mandate requires TD Wallet AND SQLALCHEMY so I think I'm shit out of luck here... :-(

Comment: The old `sqlalchemy-teradata` module (i.e. `teradata:` dialect for SQLAlchemy as opposed to `teradatasql:`) provides an interface between SQLAlchemy and the Teradata ODBC driver, so TD Wallet would work with that. Note however that module is deprecated, so may not be an acceptable choice either.